# terraform dynamic block based on variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I currently have a module that builds a storage account

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "data_lake_storage" {
  name                     = var.name
  resource_group_name      = var.resource_group_name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = var.sku
  account_replication_type = var.redundancy
  is_hns_enabled           = true
  tags                     = var.tags
}
```

Our developers will run terraform apply on their local machines to build themselves an environment to develop against. Once complete they will check in their code and our agent machines will run the terraform to build our dev, qa and live environments.

My problem now is that I need to lock down our storage account and deny public access. So I need to amend the storage account with the following

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "data_lake_storage" {
  name                     = var.name
  resource_group_name      = var.resource_group_name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = var.sku
  account_replication_type = var.redundancy
  is_hns_enabled           = true
  tags                     = var.tags

  network_rules {
    default_action = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
      var.agent_vnet_id,
      var.dbr_private_subnet_id,
      var.dbr_public_subnet_id
    ]
    bypass = ["None"]
  }
}
```

This will work when the agents run the terraform but wont work when the developers run the terraform locally, as their IP address is not in the list. To allow it to work for them I would need:

```
network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    ip_rules = [ var.client_ip_address ]
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [ azurerm_subnet.dbr-public.id, azurerm_subnet.dbr-private.id ]
    bypass = [ "None" ]
  }
```

The only solution I can think is to have a variable set to indicate whether it is a developer running the code or an agent and have the network rules section change depending on the variable. But I have no idea how to do that.

unless I am missing something obvious in my approach.

Comment: What would the variable be? Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: so this kind of works:
ip_rules = [ "${var.local == "local" ? var.client_ip_address  : "1.11.1.1" }" ]
by setting a variable TF_VAR_local=agent or local I get the values in ip_rules.
But I would like to skip it setting ip_rules altogether if TF_VAR_local was se to anything other than local

Comment: So you want only the `ip_rules` not to be set or the entire `network_rules` block?

Comment: I would like only the ip_rules to not be set if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I got it working how I wanted to:
The network rules block looks like this

```
network_rules {
    default_action = "Deny"
    ip_rules = "${var.local_or_agent == "local" ? [var.client_ip_address]  : null }"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
      var.shared_vnet_id
    ]
    bypass = ["None"]
  }
```

I then have two variables declared with default values as follows

```
variable "client_ip_address" {
  description = "client IP address"
  type        = string
  default     = "1.1.1.1"
}

variable "local_or_agent" {
  description = "client IP address"
  type        = string
  default     = "agent"
}
```

Then in the script the developers run to create their environments I set those two variables

```
TF_VAR_client_ip_address=$(wget -q -O - ipinfo.io/ip)
export TF_VAR_client_ip_address
TF_VAR_local_or_agent="local"
export TF_VAR_local_or_agent
```

If those variables are removed from the script it creates the storage account with only the vnet rule. If those variables in the scrip are present it also adds the ip_rules with the developers public ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Most resources in Azure are accessible over the internet via ARM but some sub-resourxes or configuration attributes of a resource require access to the resource endpoint itself as those resources. Most notably are storage accounts and keyvaults.

When you block internet access or restrict network access to these resource endpoints whatever machine Terraform is running from still needs access to those resource endpoints. That means whatever machine Terraform is running on needs network line of sight to those resource endpoints.

Many teams expect developers to run Terraform CLI on their local development machine to do things like run plans and occasionally do imports or other state management operations while the apply is reserved for the pipeline tool.

If the server your pipeline tool runs it's build agent on has network access but your developers workstations do not you will run into a conundrum. How to grant developers access while keeping private network turned off?

There are a couple solutions to this. Each with their own trade offs. Some better than others.

First, design your network and setup Point-to-site VPN to allow developers access to the required resources. This is not an all or nothing deal if there are other resources your developers don't need access to you can design your network and RBAC in such a way to keep them out.

Second, it called a network restriction sandwich. The idea is this: before running Terraform you open up networking to whitelist a single machines IP address, this would be the build agent machine or the Dev workstations. This will allow them to run Terraform. Then after that is done you remove this configuration. So the layers of the sandwich are: network config change, Terraform apply, network config change.

Having tried both and dealt with the pain of the second option personally. I would recommend The first option. ^_^